# How do I create the file constructor in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-native-image-picker

I need to send a File Object type to Endpoint.React Native does not support File Object type.

I will be glad if you help

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

react native can send file by FormData,just like web and use fetch to send is OK.

Comment: you don't understand my question. I want to use File type on the web.                                                                          example : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File